# Getting Error in Asp.Net Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core

An exception of type > System.InvalidOperationException occurred in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll` but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Missing 'userSecretsId' in '`E:\Pr\Books\src\Books\project.json`'.

Comment: Have you installed UserSecrets on your machine? If not it will search for the information in the project.json or the environment variables

Comment: Wow it working thanks.. http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html

Comment: since resolved your problem. Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed UserSecrets on your machine? If not it will search for the information in the project.json or the environment variables